# wmii - How do I get TightVNCServer to start the WMII desktop environment instead of default Xsession?

Tags: vnc, lxsession, white-screen

How do I modify the `~/.vnc/xstartup` file to make it start WMII when I type the `tightvncserver` command and try to connect?

This is what I replaced the `/etc/X11/Xsession` line with:

```
/usr/bin/lxsession -s wmii -e LXDE &
```

... but it doesn't work. First I got this error:

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject.
```

I solved that by changing a setting in "Default applications for LXSession", I searched for `lxpolkit` and simply made that textfield blank instead, but now my desktop on the VNC client is simply blank (light gray) and I can't do anything, even right-clicking on the desktop doesn't open any menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it turned out to be much simpler than what I tried when I added my question. It was simply the following:

```
wmii &
```

Much simpler than I thought. :)